# Consumer widget is not listening to update

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am not Abel to listen changes in my main.dart file while I am using consumer widget basically I am trying to login and save accessToken in variable and I want to redirect to home page from routes when it is true
following is mine main.dart file

```
    return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => UserBookings(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => AuthenticationDetails(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => FetchPlaces()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => Authclass(),
            ),
          ],
          child: Consumer<AuthenticationDetails>(
              builder: (context, value, _) => MaterialApp(
                    
                    
                      primarySwatch: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    home: value.isAuth ? PrepareRide() : Otp(),
routes: {
                  'verifyotp': (context) =>
                      value.isAuth ? const PrepareRide() : const VerifyOtp(),
                  'mapview': (context) => const PrepareRide(),
                },
```

following is my login class

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'cabapi.dart';

class AuthenticationDetails extends ChangeNotifier {
  int? sessionId;
  String? acessToken;
  DateTime? acessTokenExpiryDate;
  String? refreshToken;
  DateTime? refreshTokenExpiryDate;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String? get token {
    if (acessTokenExpiryDate != null &&
        acessTokenExpiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        acessToken != null) {
      return acessToken;
    }
    return null;
  }

  bool get refresh {
    return refreshtoken != null;
  }

  String? get refreshtoken {
    if (refreshTokenExpiryDate != null &&
        refreshTokenExpiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        refreshToken != null) {
      return acessToken;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> registerUser(String? phoneNumber, BuildContext context) async {
    final url = Ninecabsapi().urlHost + Ninecabsapi().login;
    try {
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
          body: json.encode({'mobileno': phoneNumber}));
      var userDetails = json.decode(response.body);
      //print(userDetails);
      // switch (response.statusCode) {
      //   case 201:
      //     print(acessToken);

      //     //showsnackbar(context, "logged in");
      //     break;
      // }
      sessionId = userDetails['data']['session_id'];
      acessToken = userDetails['data']['access_token'];
      acessTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['access_token_expires_in']),
      );
      refreshToken = userDetails['data']['refresh_token'];
      refreshTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['refresh_token_expires_in']),
      );
      print(isAuth);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting response and storing data in variables but not Abel to listen data can any one help me please

[you can see here consumer is not listening to my listeners when auth is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPIsA.jpg)

Comment: Would you post more code? Maybe youre getting an Exception on 'loginUser'?

Comment: Rebuild MaterialApp with difference home will not work. You need to change the route to home. Inside Home, use consumer for state management. MaterialApp is not easy to use like other widget.

Comment: @ErickLanfordXenes I had updated the code there is no exception I am getting the response

Comment: @Dante can you please explain it clearly actually I dint understand what do you mean change the route to home. Inside Home,

Comment: Try to replace the child parameter on the MultiProvider by builder: (context, _) { return  YourApp();},

Comment: builder needs a widget but it is a class so I used create

Comment: @dante actually I had used consumer to whole material app so it is not necessary to use again consumer inside home

Comment: @SantoshKumar your title assumes Consumer<AuthenticationDetails> does not rebuild. I doubt that. Please add print to confirm.

Comment: no it is not rebuilding

Comment: It's weird that notifyListeners() does not trigger a rebuild. Could you provide a mininum example that I can run by copy/paste?

Comment: ok give me your mail id so that I will give you the source files

Comment: you can use Api:http://cabtest.xyz/sessions for login and use postman to see its parameters you can copy and paste above code

Comment: The Consumer did rebuild for me. Did you add print in the Consumer ->builder method?

Comment: yeah it did not rebuild are you using the same code what I used?

Comment: I had share you my console log in question  you can see over there

Comment: I don't understand why notifyListeners() does not work for you. Could you share the minimum project to reproduce the bug? without unrelated class.

Comment: yeah share me your mail id

Comment: I had remodified the question I am trying to redirect in routes is it possible to redirect from routes

Comment: I had sent you the mail please check it

Comment: @SantoshKumar yea, you cannot create new instance of provider like this AuthenticationDetails().registerUser(). You need to acquire the provided instance by using  BuildContext: context.read<AuthenticationDetails>().registerUser()

Comment: thanks a lot it helped please post your answer so that I can vote for you